# Understanding the equivalent viscous damping formulation for a multiple degree of freedom hysteresis-damped system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I have a system with multiple degrees of freedom, undergoing viscous and hysteresis damping, with the following governing equation:

$$\mathbf{M\ddot{x}}+\mathbf{C\dot{x}}+(\mathbf{K}+i\eta\mathbf{K})\bf{x}=\bf{0} \tag{1}$$ where $\bf M$ is diagnonal, and $\bf C$ and $\bf K$ are *symmetric tridiagonal matrices*.

To enable me to simulate the system in the time domain, the standard approach is to calculate the equivalent viscous damping matrix $\mathbf{C}_{eq}$. [This paper](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0022460X10003640?token=8AF6841CB2DB203F81BB506EE0EB6E0670B269F141924891525F59F0193AA441203C677B09389E0D23DC48EC83D3913E&originRegion=eu-west-1&originCreation=20210926120536) describes the following process to calculate $\mathbf{C}_{eq}$ which I'll restate below:

1. Find the eigenvector matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}$ of the corresponding MK system from eq. (1).
2. Find the mass and stiffness modal matrices: $\bf K_m = \mathbf{\Phi^T} (\eta\bf{K) \Phi}$, and $\mathbf{M}_m = \bf \Phi^TM\Phi$.
3. Calculate the equivalent damping modal matrix: $\mathbf{C}_{m,eq} = \text{diag}\left(\frac{\bf K_{m_{i,i}}}{\omega_{n,i}}\right) $
4. Back-transform $\mathbf{C}_{m,eq}$ from step 3 to find the equivalent damping matrix: $\mathbf{C}_{eq}=\bf{\Phi^{-1}}^TC_{m,eq}\Phi^{-1}$
5. Reformulate eq. (1): $\mathbf{M\ddot{x}}+(\mathbf{C}+\mathbf{C}_{eq})\dot{x}+\mathbf{K}\bf{x}=\bf{0}$
6. In the case where there is a specific frequency range of interest, the reduced modal matrix $\bf\Phi^*$ can be used to perform the corresponding modal transformations, in which case $\bf\Phi^{-1}$ from step 4 should be replaced with $\mathbf{M}_m^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi^TM}$.

---

**My Attempt**

When attempting to implement the above into a $4\times4$ system, where I am interested in the 2${^\text{nd}}$ and 3${^\text{rd}}$ modes, the approach seems to be inconsistent due to the dimensions of the matrix multiplications, in specific:

1. I obtain $\mathbf{\Phi}_{4\times4}$, from which I extract the 2${^\text{nd}}$ and 3${^\text{rd}}$ modes to obtain $\mathbf{\Phi}^*_{4\times 2}$.
2. I obtain $\mathbf{K}_{m,2\times2} = \left({\mathbf{\Phi}_{m,4\times2}^*}\right)^T(\eta\mathbf{K}_{4\times 4})\mathbf{\Phi}_{m,4\times2}^*$ and $\mathbf{M}_{m,2\times2} = \left({\mathbf{\Phi}_{m,4\times2}^*}\right)^T\mathbf{M}_{4\times 4}\mathbf{\Phi}_{m,4\times2}^*$
3. I calculate $\mathbf{C}_{m,eq,2\times2}$, since my modal stiffness matrix $\mathbf{K}_{m,2\times2}$ is also $2\times2$.
4. Now I have to backtransform the modal damping matrix using $\mathbf{M}_{m,2\times2}^{-1} \mathbf{\Phi}^T_{4\times4} \mathbf{M}_{4\times4}$ since my reduced eigenvalue matrix $\mathbf{\Phi}^*{4\times2}$ is not square.

However as you can see the matrix dimensions are not compatible for the multiplication in step 4 to be performed. Assuming then that there is a typo, the author might have meant $\mathbf{M}_{m,2\times2}^{-1} \left(\mathbf{\Phi}^*_{4\times2}\right)^T \mathbf{M}_{4\times4}$, in which case does work to produce a result. However in that case the $\mathbf{C}_{eq}$ I obtain after the back-transformation is not *symmetric tridiagonal*, which is what I would expect from an equivalent viscous damping. Any insight on the two above problems I am facing would be appreciated.